# Use of start method in ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I have following code in one my team projects:

```
this.context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test_spring.xml");       
this.task = ((Task)this.context.getBean("task"));
this.context.registerShutdownHook();
this.context.start();
```

I have never before seen "start" method being called and i dont understand whats the need of start method?

[Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#start%28%29) says:

```
Start this component. Should not throw an exception if the component is already running.
In the case of a container, this will propagate the start signal to all components that apply.
```

But i dont understand what does it imply. Can someone explain what can go wrong if start method is not called or how does it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a [`ApplicationListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) interface to listen for various [`ApplicationEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html)s. One such event is the [`ContextStartedEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStartedEvent.html). You can create a bean of some class that implements `ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>`.

When you invoke `start()`, the `ApplicationContext` will publish such an event and all  `ApplicationListener` beans registered for `ContextStartedEvent` (they get registered automatically if found in the context) will get notified.

If you don't call `start()`, they will not get notified.